# How to bulk insert a csv file?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
BULK INSERT krissmall
FROM 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\misskrisdata_small.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

**ERROR 1064 (42000)**: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BULK
INSERT krissmall FROM 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\misskrisdata_small.' at
line 1

Can someone please tell me where went wrong? Or some other reasons behind this. I stared at this query for a long time, and looked it up a lot but I cannot find where it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious where you looked up `BULK INSERT` since that doesn't seem to be supported by MySQL at all. Maybe you're reading MS SQL documentation and confusing the two.

What you want is [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) which can parse CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged `phpmyadmin` which leads me to believe that you are trying to execute this query from a remote server (possibly a web host). The remote server can't connect to your local drive. You must import through phpMyAdmin or upload the file you wish to import to a directory that phpMyAdmin can see.